# How to count more than one value in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column named direction. This columns has just 1 or 0 int value. For every 1 or zero there is and ID couple. For example:

```
ID1 ID2 direction
1    2     1
2    3     0
2    4     1
4    1     1
1    2     0
2    3     1
```

I need a select query in order to take 0 counts and 1 counts for every ID1 and ID2 pair. How can I do that?

Edit:

Result table should look like this: (Numbers does not match with above example)

```
ID1 ID2 0count 1count
1    2     1     4
2    3     2     2
2    2     1     1
```

Comment: can you please show your result table as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Jolly : Zohar has given perfect solution

Comment: @SandipPatel I added result table. Can you guys tell me why you mark this question as not shows any research effort? How can you reach that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is your friend:

```
SELECT ID1, 
       ID2, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountDirection0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountDirection1,
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID1, ID2
```